# move full-text-search catalog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, catalog

I'm have a SQL Server 2005 database that has the data and logs on their own drives and have created a full text search for the first time and looks like i missed the part where i needed to spec the location the catalog was saved to and wound up having it on my c drive.

my c drive is for OS only.

how can i move the catalog to another location on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005, [follow this procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

> To move a data or log file as part of
>   a planned relocation, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Run the following statement.
>
>    ```
>    ALTER DATABASE database_name SET OFFLINE
>    ```
> 2. Move the file or files to the new
>      location.
> 3. For each file moved, run the following
>      statement.
>
>    ```
>    ALTER DATABASE database_name MODIFY FILE ( 
>        NAME = logical_name,
>        FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name' )
>    ```
> 4. Run the following statement.
>
>    ```
>    ALTER DATABASE database_name SET ONLINE
>    ```
> 5. Verify the file change by running the
>      following query.
>
>    ```
>    SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc
>    FROM sys.master_files
>    WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'<database_name>');
>    ```